# wp_create_nonce() in REST API makes user->ID zero

Tags: ajax, nonce

I have trouble with `wp_create_nonce()` and `wp_verify_nonce()`.

The root of my problem is both the way nonces are created and the place where I generate nonces.

Looking at the codes of `wp_create_nonce()` and `wp_verify_nonce()`, I see that nonces are a hash value created from multiple factors including `$uid`, which is a `user id of current user`.

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$uid = (int) $user->ID;
if ( ! $uid ) {
    /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/pluggable.php */
   $uid = apply_filters( 'nonce_user_logged_out', $uid, $action );

}
$token = wp_get_session_token();
$i = wp_nonce_tick();
return substr( wp_hash( $i . '|' . $action . '|' . $uid . '|' . $token, 'nonce' ), -12, 10 );
```

I create the nonce under REST API and verify the nonce in normal page. However, I also find that `$uid` becomes 0 in REST API (dunno why, but somewhere I saw this and tested it myself. Yes, there's no user id inside REST). So, the `$uid` in my REST function and the `$uid` in my page become different.

[1] I create `_wpnonce` in REST API. Below is a pseudo-code for my function in REST.

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function() {
    register_rest_route( 'view/', '/customers/', array(
        'methods' => 'POST',
        'callback' => 'fnc_view_customer_in_table_format'
    ));
});

if( !function_exists( 'fnc_view_customer_in_table_format' ) ) {
    function fnc_view_customer_in_table_format(WP_REST_Request $request ) {

    //*** Code omitted on purpose ***

    $data .= '<form action="'. get_the_permalink( $post->ID ) .'" id="_form-view" name="_form-view" method="post">';
    $data .= '<input type="hidden" id="_wpnonce" name="_wpnonce" value="'. wp_create_nonce( 'view_post-'. $post->ID ) .'" />';
    $data .= '<input type="hidden" id="_post_id" name="_post_id" value="'. $post->ID. '" />';
    $data .= '<input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-link" value="'. get_the_title( $post->ID ) .'">';
    $data .= '</form>';

    //*** Code omitted on purpose ***

    $result = array( 'msg' => $data, 'error' => false );
}
```

[2] Above `$data` is returned as a response and is echoed in normal page. And I verify the nonce here. This is a normal wordpress page.

```
<?php
get_header();

$wpnonce = $_REQUEST['_wpnonce'];
$post_id = $_REQUEST['_post_id'];
if( !wp_verify_nonce( $wpnonce, 'view_post-'. $post_id ) ) {
    die( 'Security check' );
}

?>

//*** Omitted: HTML Codes ***

<?php
get_footer();
```

So, I presume that the only solution is let Wordpress REST recognize current_user. How do I achieve this, or am I thinking the wrong way?

** EDIT **
As a workaround, I changed my `wp_verify_nonce` process as below.

```
// nonce is created in REST API, which doesn't have UID
// In order to replicate the same, set UID to 0 here
$uid = (int) wp_get_current_user()->ID;
wp_set_current_user(0);

// Nonce check
if( !wp_verify_nonce( $wpnonce, 'view_post-'. $post_id ) ) {
die( 'Security check' );
}

// Now get the current user back in place
wp_set_current_user( $uid );
```

Anyways, this doesn't look beautiful. What would be a better practice to solve my problem?

Comment: Could elaborate on where your code `[2]` lives? Is it hooked onto an action? If so, which? (It doesn't appear as you're using WordPress' REST API however).

Comment: I have a page (let's say page A) that calls the REST function `fnc_view_customer_in_table_format()` and echoes the response, which is basically a HTML code for `<form></form>`. Once the `<form>` is submitted, page [2] is called and the nonce is verified in page [2].

Answer (score 1):

I know it pasts a long time of this question.

But I had the same issue and it was difficult for me to find some documentation about it. I had the same problem, for some reason wp_create_nonce and wp_verify_nonce they bot retrieve different hash. So I notice the problem was the $User->ID or $uid that these two function uses to hash the nonce.

I just trying to create the nonce inside the script but for some reason the uid become 0, and what I did, is to create the nonce before and outside the script block and print the value inside the script.

First it was like this (WRONG):

```
  var action     = 'submit_user_review';                  
  var ajax_nonce = '<?php echo wp_create_nonce('security'); ?>';

  jQuery.ajax({
       url: my_ajax_object.ajax_url,
       type: 'POST',
       data: {
           action: action,
           listing_id: rest_id,
           review: comment,
           rate: rate,
           security_review: ajax_nonce,
       },
       beforeSend: function() {
           // Show full page LoadingOverlay
           jQuery.LoadingOverlay("show");
      },
```

and after like this (GOOD):

```
  <?php //Set Your Nonce
      $ajax_nonce_review = wp_create_nonce( "submit-user-review" );
  ?>
  <script>                  
  var action = 'submit_user_review';

  jQuery.ajax({
       url: my_ajax_object.ajax_url,
       type: 'POST',
       data: {
           action: action,
           listing_id: rest_id,
           review: comment,
           rate: rate,
           security_review: '<?php echo $ajax_nonce_review; ?>',
       },
       beforeSend: function() {
           // Show full page LoadingOverlay
           jQuery.LoadingOverlay("show");
      },
```

And that fix my problem, literally spend one day trying to figure it out this.

I hope it helps somebody else.